# Update listview items after adding them programmatically in WPF using VB.Net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, listviewitem

I’m vb.net developer that’s new to WPF.

I’m converting a Windows Form app to WPF and I’m having a problem updating my listview items as I add them. I have a communication process within the app that connects to a server to send or download information to/from it using a tcp connection. This process updates a listview to show the status of the communication with the server. But the items are not displayed as I add them, instead they are all visible when the process finishes. I will like to refresh the items as they are added. In Windows Forms I used the code:

```
 ListView1.EnsureVisible(ListView1.Items.Count - 1)
```

witch will ensure that the last item was visible in the listview. That code however does not works in WPF. Im looking for an alternative to achive this. Any suggestion is welcome even if it envolves using another element rather than a listview. Or if someone knows an alternative using C# it is also welcomed.

My VB code that updates my listview is the following:

```
Private Sub DebugMsg(ByVal Message As String, Optional ByVal NewLine As Boolean = True)
    If NewLine = True Then
        Dim item As New ListViewItem
        item.Content = Message
        Me.ListView1.Items.Add(item)
        item = Nothing
    ElseIf NewLine = False Then
        If ListView1.Items.Count > 0 Then
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).Content = Message
        Else
            Dim item As New ListViewItem
            item.Content = Message
            Me.ListView1.Items.Add(item)
            item = Nothing
        End If
    End If
    Me.ListView1.Items.Refresh()
End Sub
```

This sub is used every time I want to update the listview to show the status of the communication.

My XAML Code is the following:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView1" Margin="10,101,10,10" Background="#FF0C0C0C" Foreground="Cyan" FontSize="20" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridView.ColumnHeaderContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu/>
        </GridView.ColumnHeaderContextMenu>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="475"/>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Thanks in advanced!